# Yii Framework: Empty variables after form validation fails

Tags: php, yii

I have a form with two input text fields:

```
<input id="ModelName_test_0" name="ModelName[test][0]" type="text">
<input id="ModelName_test_1" name="ModelName[test][1]" type="text">
```

These input fields get generated with the following commands:

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'test[0]'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'test[1]'); ?>
```

Now, when I submit the form I see the values in the POST request. However, when the form submit fails then I can not get the values back into the input fields. Printing the model it shows that there are no values for $test; - is this because $test is an array in the form?

Even after the validation all values are still assigned to the variables:

```
if($model->validate()) {
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_POST);
   return;
}
```

This returns:

```
[ModelName] => Array  
        (
            [test] => Array  
                (
                    [0] => myFirstInputField  
                    [1] => mySecondInputField
                )
        )
```

So the values are in the POST but after the failed validation they are gone and I get empty variables:

```
[ModelName] => Array  
        (
            [test] => 
        )
```

The variable *test* is declared *safe* in the validation rules.

**What I want to achieve is:**
If the validation fails put the entered values back into the appropriate input text fields.

Any pointers in the right direction would be helpful :)

Comment: May I see the controller handling this?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this but I think what you need is to enable ajax validation in the controller for the post action and then when it fails it will fail in the form and the form will be re-populated

Comment: can you paste your controller code ?

Comment: How are you setting the model values on the POST?

Comment: Mark your own answer as accepted for future reference :)

Comment: @Örs: I have to wait one day to do so. Will do so tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article on the yiiframework.com website which helped me solving this issue: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

This is the sample code which you would put it your controller:

```
public function actionBatchUpdate()
{
    // retrieve items to be updated in a batch mode
    // assuming each item is of model class 'Item'
    $items=$this->getItemsToUpdate();
    if(isset($_POST['Item']))
    {
        $valid=true;
        foreach($items as $i=>$item)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['Item'][$i]))
                $item->attributes=$_POST['Item'][$i];
            $valid=$item->validate() && $valid;
        }
        if($valid)  // all items are valid
            // ...do something here
    }
    // displays the view to collect tabular input
    $this->render('batchUpdate',array('items'=>$items));
}
```

And this is what the view would look like:

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Count</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]name"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]price"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]count"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($item,"[$i]description"); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>

<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Both code snippets are taken from yiiframework.com where you can find more details on how to use 'Tabular Inputs': http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that [CHtml::activeTextField](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeTextField-detail) expects a model and one of its attributes as parameters. If the attribute is named `test` then have `$form->textField($model,'test');`. After your form is submitted, either `test` doesn't have any values or it is an array (check this to confirm, either echoing it's value or doing a `print_r` on `$model->attributes`).

Comment: Yes, it is an array. Using the posted 'Tabular Input' collecting method did the trick in processing the passed array.